# How to compute the slope error of a linear regression using scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-regression

To compute the slope error of a linear regression (using scipy) I wanted to use

```
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
sd_slope = (len(x)*std_err**2)/(len(x)*(x**2).sum()-x.sum()**2)
```

. The equation is taken from Wikipedia. Why is this so wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to compute at the end is variance of the estimated slope i.e. square of std error of slope. It turns out that `std_err` returned by `.linregress` is already the std error of the slope.

But if you still want to calculate it manually, you need to replace `std_err` in your equation with `s` (the estimate of standard deviation of residuals) which is `sqrt(SSE / (n-2))` where `n == len(x)`, the sample size. So, in code:

```
# Get the predicted values
yhat = intercept + slope * x

# Get SSE i.e. sum of squared errors (or RSS: residual sum of squares)
SSE = np.sum((y - yhat)**2)

# Calculate the "s" the estimate of standard deviation of residuals
s = np.sqrt(SSE / (n-2))

# Now your equation (it will give variance)
your_eq = (n*s**2) / (n*(x**2).sum() - x.sum()**2)

# Square root of the above value gives the std error
sd_slope = np.sqrt(your_eq)

# You can see that it is equal to (within precision) std_err of scipy
assert np.isclose(sd_slope, std_err)
```